# How does rails params are created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm having a trouble when I'm trying to user params.require(...).permit(...)

In my application I received the follow param dic:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Vatzcb5tgTu2+wL1t6Of+FbIK8Ibp+tM03Naai4b2OU=",
 "/login"=>{"username_or_email"=>"jonatasteixeira",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Save /login" }
```

I would like to know why the my key received the "/login" name.

My view:

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<%= form_for(login_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username_or_email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username_or_email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', root_path %>
```

In my controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /login
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /login
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_emai(session_params[:username_or_email]) || User.find_by_username(session_params[:username_or_email]) 
      if @user && @user.authenticate(session_params[:password])
        session[:current_user_id] = @user.id
        flash[:notice] = 'You are logged in'
      else
        flash[:notice] = 'Invalid password, username or email'
      end
  end

  private
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def session_params
      logger.info :login
      params.require("/login").permit(:username_or_email, :password)
  end
end
```

I dont want to use "/login" as key, I would like to use :login. Some one knows how could I adjust it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rafal pointed out, you could code your call to `form_for` like this to get rid of the awkward `/login` key in your params:

```
<%= form_for(:login) do |f| %>
```

Strong parameters are really only for scenarios where you are doing mass assignment on an object. If you were *creating* the user, for example, then you would probably want to pass the attributes into the `new` initializer method using strong parameters.

```
@user = User.new(session_params)
```

But because you're not doing mass assignment in this case, you can just pass in the values directly without a `session_params` method:

```
# POST /login
def create
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:login][:username_or_email]) || User.find_by(username: params[:login][:username_or_email]) 
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:login][:password])
    session[:current_user_id] = @user.id
    flash[:notice] = 'You are logged in'
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Invalid password, username or email'
  end
end
```

The whole point of strong parameters is so no one can pass in extra attributes. In your `/login` scenario, your code is completely in control of the values being handled, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: OK.. I did this adjusts but. I'm getting this error: "param is missing or the value is empty: login"

Comment: If you reload the form and inspect one of the fields, does it look something like this? `<input type="text" name="login[username_or_password]" value="" />`

Comment: P.S. You should be using `find_by(email: ...)` and `find_by(username: ...)` in Rails 4. I think the dynamic finders like `find_by_email` and `find_by_username` are deprecated in version 4.

Answer (score 1):

[**Form_For**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

When you use `form_for`, Rails expects an `object` to be passed so it can build a variety of different elements from it:

> [The form_for] helper is designed to make working with resources much easier
>   compared to using vanilla HTML.

The problem is you're passing a route to this method, which I'm surprised actually works.

--

[**form_tag**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)

You'll be better using a `symbol`, as recommended by the accepted answer, or by using [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html), which doesn't require an object:

```
<%= form_tag login_path do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :username_or_email %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
    <%= submit_button_tag "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

This will remove the references to the "login" key of your params, and will give you the ability to do this (no need for `require`):

```
params.permit(:username_or_email, :password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`<%= form_for(login_path) do |f| %>`

use

`<%= form_for(:login) do |f| %>`

Comment: I did it, but its not fix my trouble, the params remains iqual!